# Which Trust Flow and Citation Flow matters? Domain's Trust Flow Citation Flow? or URL's Trust Flow Citation Flow?

Tags: seo, google-search

```
TF = Trust Flow
CF = Citation Flow
DA = Domain Authority
PA = Page Authority
```

From yesterday, I am stuck to one thing. I am working on my project, and will be doing KW analysis to get some low competition keywords for my niche. And at the same time, I was analyzing the difficulty of my niche. Everything is going great so far except this thing that I don't know which TF CF to consider!

I mean, when you are expecting some authority sites to link you, what TF CF should be considered? Should I watch for TF CF on the page where my site is linked (i.e should I check TF CF of specific URL?)? OR should I check TF CF of the homepage of site (i.e domain's TF CF?).

Yesterday, I was analyzing howtogeek dot com for test. When I searched for its domain TF and CF, I got results like TF: 37 and CF: 46 but when I searched TF CF of one of its URL (article page) then I got results like TF: 27 and CF: 39. I am super confused right now. Which one to consider? Which TF CF is a ranking factor? Is it domain's TF CF? or is it URL TF CF?

If I am getting a link from this domain (www,abc,com) and its domain's TF is 40 and CF is 50. But they included my link in this article www,abc,com/article.html whose TF is nearly 10 and CF is 15. Which TF and CF will google consider for my ranking positions? Will it use domain's TF and CF or URL (article's) TF CF where my link is included.

Comment: Instead of using abbreviations that people may not understand you should use the whole word. As of right now I have no idea what this question is about. Please edit this question and remove the abbreviations.

Comment: You are worrying about too much. MOZ has you amp'ed up over B.S. detail. Just create a decent site that users want and go for links from decent sites. Forget the metrics. You will drive yourself crazy. Sites are about people not machines.

Comment: @closetnoc is 100% right, it is not powerful as most of people think. They follow link pattern, there are too many popular and high quality website which they still did not discover.

Comment: You actually benefit more from just a decent handful of moderate links than a few more valuable links. Link profiles are analyzed and a link pattern of only a few higher value links may be seen as suspect where a good spread of link quality from high to low would represent a more organic pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Let's don't focus on other people metrics, and let me tell you the truth about the links.

**Good links you/me can't build, it should earn by naturally, and Google is pretty smart on that**

When we talk about backlinks then many of Google metrics are changed, of course pagerank is one of them, but Google using many of other private factor like Page Expert Score.

Majestic and other link analyser(ahref, seoprofiler, moz etc) just crawl the links and calculate the value of website or webpages based on links only, while in reality Google use the content of that page from the links is pointing to some other webpage. There are no any link analyser goes deeper like Google crawler go. Do other link analyster use the webpage title, heading content and paragraph content while calculating their metrics, absolutely not, they just do calculation based on links only, while Google calculate their private metrics based on query/keyword from both side of webpage(from someone webpage to your webpage).

Let's come to the your question.

If you get links from any domain name to your site or webpage then some of Google metrics will get affect but it does not powerful as you think, because as I said, Google check the webpage (whole webpage content not just anchor text) from which it links to it. So if you get backlinks from any webpage like "abc.com/article.html" and the article name is "How to Get my adsense payment" and that page link to your "any of your adsense payment related page" then it will benefits you a lot, here you'll not get higher PageRank as compare to, if it links from main homepage,  but you'll get higher Google Page Expert Score and other private metrics, which can help you to rank that article well, because that is how Google identify links are natural.

Google many of factors depend on backlinks, but it will affect only if Google see those links naturally. Yes when link is dofollow then, on some of metrics you will get higher value but for others private metrics you will get zero score(For example footer links, widget links, author bio links, forum signature links and list goes so on)

Also the link analyser tool is not powerful as you think, I have put one comment on one of IBM company and I see Google see that links in few days, while other backlink analsyer still did not see that links after a year, because they still follow the link pattern.

Comment: Goyllo is perfectly right. A major portion of the link value calculation is the link itself and not page metrics. For example, where is the page linked from, what is the semantic value of the link, is the content block considered important, how relevant is the link to the source page and target page, is the link organic, what is the CTR or engagement value of the link, what is the authors authority, what is the reading level of the content, what is the expertise level of the content, and on and on. There are quite a few metrics that are measured and important to the calculation. Cheers!!